# Why can't I place downloaded rooms on to the lot?

Tags: the-sims-4

I downloaded some rooms from the Community. When I go to place them in the lot, they just don't show up. There's no indication as to why this is happening. I have sufficient funds and there's no error message. What would be causing this?

Example rooms that I can't place are the Hemlock Grove Landing by the user hmsdrco2012, Elenor Rigby Kitchen by MorganaLaFata, the Ocean Bedroom by MorganaLaFata - the list goes on, really. There's no indication as to why they can't be placed, either when placing them or when downloading them - I select the room and try to click to place it and nothing happens.

This also appears to be fairly common. In addition to [my post on the EA support forums](http://answers.ea.com/t5/The-Sims-4/Why-can-t-I-place-downloaded-rooms-on-the-lot/m-p/3610723/highlight/true#M15063), I found two other posts, without a solution as well - [here](http://answers.ea.com/t5/The-Sims-4/Can-t-bring-in-rooms-from-gallery-into-build-mode/m-p/3471405/highlight/true#M9729) and [here](http://answers.ea.com/t5/The-Sims-4/Cannot-place-custom-rooms/m-p/3516135/highlight/true#M12328).

Answer (score -1):

I've read another post and I think the problem is that you should favorite the rooms instead of putting them into your library. If you have more than 28 rooms in your library it appears that you can't place them. I can't really explain why though